# Swift - port bar graph code from obj-c

Tags: objective-c, swift

SOLUTION: Here is the GitHub link for the class I eventually created / will expand on https://github.com/ckalas/SimpleSwiftBarGraph

I'm trying to (in playground) draw a bar graph using Core Graphics. I'm basing it off this code in Obj-C:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
    CGFloat barWidth = 30;
    int count = 0;
    for (NSNumber *num in values) {
        CGFloat x = count * (barWidth + 10);
        CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(x, height - ([num floatValue] * height), barWidth, [num floatValue] * height);
        CGContextAddRect(context, barRect);
        count++;
    }
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

I'm trying to convert this, but at the second line, Xcode doesn't know about UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(). Can anyone offer help?

EDIT: Here is my current code...issues now are in the for loop where I commented, no matter what combination of stuff I try I cannot get that line to work. Just errors can't convert type to type, I've tried declaring the array as an [NSNumber], no luck.

```
 class CustomView: UIView {
        init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
        }
    override func drawRect(rect: GCRect) {
        let values: [UInt8] = [1,2,3]
        let height = self.bounds.size.height
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextClearRect(context, self.frame)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor!);
        let barWidth = 30.0 as CGFloat
        var count = 0 as CGFloat
        for number in values {
            let x = count * (barWidth + 10) as CGFloat
            let barRect = CGRectMake(x, (height - number*height), barWidth, number*height) // issues here can't convert one type to another
        CGContextAddRect(context, barRect)
        count++
    }
    CGContextFillPath(context)

}
```

Comment: Show your Swift code.

Comment: Have you imported UIKit? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: it says no such module as UIKit, which is odd.
The error is: use of unresolved identifier UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

Comment: had to change to a iOS playground, seems all good now. shall try do the rest

Comment: Updated the code, other issues now..namely :
let barRect = CGRectMake(x, (height - number*height), barWidth, number*height) // issues here can't convert one type to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `values` array to be of type `[CGFloat]`.  I made a few other stylistic changes (removed semicolons, `CGColor` is already implicitly unwrapped so `!` is not needed, and prefer type declaration to cast).

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let values: [CGFloat] = [0.3, 0.6, 0.9]
        let height = self.bounds.size.height
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextClearRect(context, self.frame)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
        let barWidth:CGFloat = 30.0
        var count:CGFloat = 0
        for number in values {
            let x = count * (barWidth + 10)
            let barRect = CGRectMake(x, (height - number*height), barWidth, number*height)
            CGContextAddRect(context, barRect)
            count++
        }
        CGContextFillPath(context)
    }
}
```

The values in the `values` array should range from `0.0` for no bar height to `1.0` for full bar height.

Comment: I arrived at that conclusion too, however it gives me an error in playground: Jul 24 21:42:20 iMac.local MyPlayground[27935] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, using my code, if I then create the view with `var test = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200))` I get a bar graph.

Comment: I had changed the function away from drawRect to another name, with drawRect it works. Well, I get 3 equal grey lines on a black background.

Comment: Yes.  It has to be `drawRect`.  The system only gives you a valid context inside of `drawRect`.

Comment: any idea why the bars are equal heights?

Comment: The values in your `values` array should range from `0.0` for no bar height to `1.0` for full bar height.